# Step CI workflow runtime error with slash in path

Tags: yaml, schema, openapi

My problem is when I run the test (`stepci run fakedata.yaml`) I have the error (in the image):

[image: input must not start with a slash when using prefixUrl]

[image: Portion of code file name -> fakedata.yaml]

I tried to check the validation with some website and I have no problem with my YAML file. I tried to remove the slash but the the test still shows the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add `config.http.baseURL` to your YAML config. Here's an example:

```yaml
version: "1.1"
name: Status Check
config:
  http:
    baseURL: https://example.com
tests:
  example:
    steps:
      - name: GET request
        http:
          url: /
          method: GET
          check:
            status: /^20/
```